# Absolutely continuous function vanishes on a set, does its derivative vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, absolute-continuity

Let $g:[0,T] \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded measurable function.

Let  $f(t)=\int_0^t g(\tau) \ d\tau +a$ for some $a\ne 0$. Then, $f$ is absolutely continuous and almost everywhere differentiable.

Assume there exists $E \subset [0,T]$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in E$.

The question: Is there a subset $E' \subset E$ such that  $\mu(E')=\mu(E)$ and $f'(t)=0$ for all  $t \in E'$?  [Recall $f'(t)=g(t)$]

Comment: $f$ is automatically bounded because $g$ is bounded

Comment: thanks, I have edited it

Comment: $f$ is not only absolutely continuous, but even Lipschitz.

Comment: Why is it Lipschitz?

Comment: Because if $|g(x)|\le M$ everywhere then for $a<b$ we have $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b g(x)\,dx \le \int_a^b M\,dx = (b-a)M$ and similarly from below.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You need some absolute values there.

Comment: @zhw.: That's the "similarly from below". I'm showing $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \le M$; that it is $\ge -M$ goes similarly.

Comment: thanks but how does it help the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Let $E^*$ be the subset of $E$ where $f'$ exist. $\mu(E^*)=\mu(E)$ since $f'$ exist almost everywhere.

Pick any $x_0\in E^*$ which is not isolated, so we have a sequence $\{x_n\}_n\subset E^*$ that converges to $x_0$.

$f'(x_0)$ exists. Therefore,

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{0-0}{x_n-x_0}=0.$$

We only need $f$ to be constant here, doesn't have to be $0$.

Set of all isolated points in $E^*$ must be countable, thus has a measure of $0$.